# Copy files with python program after it starts

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

I need a python script that will watch directory changes every 5 minutes and copy only added files. Do not copy existing files from the  source directory. Copy files after the program is started. My program copies files when I delete files on the destination. My python version is 3.6.32

Hear are my code:

```
import os, time, subprocess, sys, shutil

t = 5
os.chdir('C:\\') 

print(os.path.isdir("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\source\\"))

path_to_watch = ("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\source\\")
before = dict ([(f, None) for f in os.listdir (path_to_watch)])

dir_src = ("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\source\\")
dir_dst = ("D:\\dest\\")

while True:
    for filename in os.listdir(dir_src):
        if filename.endswith('.txt'):
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(dir_src + filename), os.path.join(dir_dst + filename))
            time.sleep(t)
```

Comment: fyi `before = {f: None for f in os.listdir(path_to_watch)}` is cleaner and more efficient

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are having?

Comment: what if a file got deleted in source directory? Should that be reflected in destination directory?

Comment: if `t=5`, then `time.sleep(t)` will not sleep for 5 minutes. It will sleep for 5 seconds. https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep

Comment: I'd rather schedule the execution of the script in your OS (using cron in Linux) and keep the script itself as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code,I modified your code a little. It will copy files from source directory to destination. Once it copied one file it will not copy the file even if it is deleted in source or destination. It will copy only newly added files.

```
import os, time, shutil

path_to_watch = "x/y/z/source"
destination = "a/b/c/destination"

source_files = set(os.listdir(path_to_watch))   # all the file names in the source directory is stored here.
new_files = set()    # this is for new files, new files will be updated in source_files too.

while True:
    for name in new_files:
        if name.endswith('.txt'):
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(path_to_watch,name), destination)   # copy files presnt in new_files
    time.sleep(5*60)

    new_files = set(os.listdir(path_to_watch))   # get current files present in source_directory
    new_files = new_files - source_files         # check if there are actually new files 
    if new_files:     # if there is a new file
        source_files = source_files.union(new_files)      # add that to source_file
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But when program starts it copies all existing files first then works good. How can stop copying all files when program starts.

Comment: I have updated the code. Try it and let me know if it works